# Problems with Callbacks Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, callback, request

How would I use callbacks in this case? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've looked at explanations and still can't wrap my head around this concept.

Here's a snippet:

```
function retrieveTransactionInfo(transactionUrl) {
    request(transactionUrl, function (error, response, body) {
        // Parse JSON here
        // Set variables accordingly
        console.log('1');
    });
}

function getTransactionInfo(data, callback) {
    callback(data);
}


$('#search-btn').click(function() {

    getTransactionInfo(transactionUrl, retrieveTransactionInfo);
    console.log('2');
```

What it's doing is running the console log '2' first instead of '1'. How would I make it go to 1 then 2 instead? or should I structure my code completely different?

Comment: That's the whole point of asynchronicity, unless somehow you block the callback until the `console.log('2')` is done, you can't predict the order in which they are executed. It could very well be that on some occasions you see the `1` first.

Comment: Request is asynchronous, console log '2' happens before the callback is resolved.

Comment: I would recommend not to use callbacks but 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

the log '2' first is correct, because get request is done asynchronously. In other words, the getTransactionInfo immediately returns and the engine executes the next line.

Later, when the async request is over, the callback is called, and the '1' output is done. You can't do otherwise if your API does async requests.